# How to fix SecurityException "signer information does not match signer information [...]" during compilation with EclipseLink 3.x?

Tags: java, maven, eclipselink

`mvn install` fails due to

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project project1-jar: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.0.v20171222-5074888): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-86] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.0.v20171222-5074888): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [persistenceUnitName] in the class [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.SEPersistenceUnitInfo] is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.SharedCacheMode"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[persistenceUnitName-->@name]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.SEPersistenceUnitInfo --> [])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException
-> [Help 1]
```

on an entity JAR of a Java EE project. I filed a bug report some weeks ago without any feedback so far and provided a MCVE at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=528076. The compilation works fine with Eclipselink <= 2.6.x.

A [google search](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=class+%22javax.persistence.SharedCacheMode%22%27s+signer+information+does+not+match+signer+information+of+other+classes+in+the+same+package&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=cFNLWpeBCarL8geSxrGICQ) brings me to the bug report referenced above.